# How to use grep command to filter a log file for a specific keyword within particular timestamp?

Tags: grep

So

```
      grep "xyz" file.log
```

will print all the lines having xyz as a key word and

```
      grep "01/APR/2014:16:3[5-9]" file,log
```

will print lines within that time range.How to use both the feature i.e a key word filter within a time range?

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe your two greps together:

```
grep “xyz” file.log | grep “01/APR/2014:16:3[5-9]”
```

The first grep will parse out all the lines with xyz, the second grep will winnow that list down by the date given.  Depending on your data set, reversing the greps could be faster.

Comment: I want to filter from 3:50 am to 4:37 am ? what would be the grep command?